# I'm unable to change the background color of my image using external css

Tags: html, css

```
body {
    background-color: #f6f7d4;
}

h1, h3, hr {
    color: #68b8ab;
}

hr {
    width: 100px;
    border-style: dotted none none;
    border-color: gray;
    border-width: 5px;
}

img {
    background-color: black;
}
```

The above one is my external css code, but it doesn't work on my html page as you see in the image below.

[image: screenshot of my html website]

Comment: Hello, can you share your html code ? I think you're trying to change the yellow color. Do you linked your external css to your html ?

Comment: An image is an image... CSS has no ability to change parts of it. Unless you start overlaying opacity-based elements over the top, but that's not going to be easy or look good. Think of it this way: you've asked it to change the "background-color"... but exactly how is a browser supposed to know what the "background" **is**?

Comment: Wait, are you expecting to change the color of the sky in that photo using css or I misunderstood you?

Comment: Uday, you need to put your `<img>` inside a `<div>`. Give that `<div>` a width. Now, when you try to change the `background-color`, you change it on the `<div>`, not `<image>`.

Answer (score 0):

```css
img{
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<img src='https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/Img/logos/so/so-icon.png?v=c78bd457575a'/>
```

As said in comment, if you have plain images you will not be able to see the background color as the images will cover it all. It will work only with images with transparency.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it's not possible to change colors IN photos/images, but you can add a filter on to it, for example `filter: hue-rotate(50deg);` (skew the hue to change all colors in the photo) or `filter: grayscale(30%);`

I would name the image with a css class so you don't target all images on your site, something like this:

```
<img class="portrait" src="../path/to/img/my-portrait.jpg">
```

And then the css:

```
img.portrait {
  filter: grayscale(30%);
}
```